# Wrapping a class with additional features outside the project

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, c#-6.0

I have a class in Project1 class library

```
class MyClass
{

[CustomAttribute]
public string prop1 {get;set;}

public string prop2 {get;set;}

}
```

I have: `CustomAttribute` depends on a 3rd party library which I dont want to include within `MyClass`.

Is there a way in which I can wrap the `CustomAttribute` of `MyClass` with `prop1` outside the `project1` and in a new wrapper `project2` that includes the `Project1`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to have a project2 exposing another class, you can always make that property virtual and override it in the project2 class (a class that whould inherit from the project1 class.

Project 1

```csharp
namespace Project1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public virtual string prop1 { get; set; }

        public string prop2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Project 2

```csharp
namespace Project2
{
    public class MyClass2 : Project1.MyClass
    {
        [CustomAttribute]
        public override string prop1 { get; set; }

        public string prop2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question seems to be about `CustomAttribute`... Not `prop1`.

Comment: And he does not want to have the CustomAtrribute assembly referenced in project1, while he wants a wrapper of sorts in project2 with a reference to said assembly. So he can have the reference in project2. Hence, the answer is about CustomAttribute.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen: The question is about hiding `CustomAttribute` in one project, rather, not using that attribute, but then using it in another project to reduce the unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question. However... If the 3rd-party library has specified `[AttributeUsage (Inherited = false)]` then this would not work. Default is `true` so chances are good. :)

Comment: Thanks @JCabello . Is it also possible to make this class injectable during runtime?